# Proof of the equivalence of the two definitions of heavy-tailed distributions

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Heavy-tailed distributions have two equivalent definitions:

For any $\lambda>0$, the moment generating function of the distribution (denoted by $F$) blows up:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\lambda x}\mathrm{d}F(x)=+\infty$$
or

For any $\lambda>0$, the decrease of the tail probability of $F$ is slower than exponentially increase:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{\lambda x}(1-F(x))=+\infty$$
That the second definition implies the first one is not difficult to prove, but how to give a proof to its converse, i.e. how to derive the second definition from the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{\lambda x}(1-F(x))=+\infty$$.

Fix $y>0$ to be a point in $\mathbb{R}$. The idea being that we place $y$ to be on the positive tail of the distribution. We can say that the integral is at least as big as $\int_y^\infty e^{\lambda x}f(x)dx \geq e^{\lambda y}(1-F(y))$. Now we know this quantity tends to infinity as we increase $y$. We chose $y$ arbitrarily so the full integral must be infinite.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\lambda x}\mathrm{d}F(x)=+\infty$$

But this is (2) $\implies$ (1).

$(1) \implies (2)$ to follow...

Comment: ah such is life! I'll have a look at the other direction

Answer (score 1):

May be the first definition does not imply the second one, considering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813303/improper-integral-involing-exponential-and-monotone-function), the exponential distribution with parameter 1 and $\lambda$ = 1.