# Improper integral involing exponential and monotone function.

Tags: exponential-function, improper-integrals

I start by apologizing for my English, please correct if you find a typo.

I am stuck with this problem; I know the answer should normally be yes, but I am not able to prove it.
Please can somebody help (or give a counter example)?

Suppose $f$ is a monotone and bounded function and $\lambda > 0 $ a fixed real. Suppose also that $ \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) e^{\lambda x}$ is finite.

**Question**:
How can we prove that  $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) e^{\lambda x} dx$ is also finite? If not, is there a counter example?

I know that if $f$ is non decreasing, for $a > 0$ we can conclude by noticing
$\displaystyle\int_{-a}^a f(x) e^{\lambda x} dx \leq \lambda^{-1} f(a)(e^{\lambda a} - e^{-\lambda a})$. How about $f$ non increasing?

Comment: What about $f(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption is not true

Counterexample

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } x < 0 \\
    e^{-\lambda x},              & x \geq 0
\end{cases}$

Then $f$ is bounded and monotone and $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) e^{\lambda x} = 1$$ but the integral is clearly infinite

Comment: @JohnOmielan My bad, I forgot the $e^{\lambda x}$ term.

Answer (score 2):

How about the piecewise function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{ for } x < 0\\ e^{-\lambda x} \text{ for } x \ge 0\end{cases}$$

It is bounded and non-increasing, satisfies the limit property at $+\infty$, and the integral diverges.

Comment: Had the exact same idea, just a bit slower +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer.